# JTable cant accept the values from String array

Tags: java, swing, jtable, abstracttablemodel

Hey guys i am building a java application in which i have a jtable and i would like to have fixed columns from a string array.

My code is:

```
final String[] names = { "Id", "Description", "Type", "Price per Unit", "Quantity" };
        JTable table = new JTable(new AbstractTableModel() {



             @Override
             public String getColumnName(int c) {
                    return "lol";
             }

             public int getRowCount() {
                 return products.size();
             }

             public int getColumnCount() {
                 return 5;
             }

             public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
                 Product p = products.get(row);
                 if(col == 0){
                     return p.getId();
                 }
                 if(col == 1){
                     return p.getDescription();
                 }
                 if(col == 2){
                     if(p.getClass() == Service.class){
                         return "Service";
                     }else{
                         return "Item";
                     }
                 }
                 if(col == 3){
                     if(p.getClass() == Service.class){
                         Service service = (Service)p;
                         return service.getNumberOfHours();
                     }else{
                         Item item = (Item) p;
                         return item.getPricePerItem();
                     }
                 }
                 if(col == 4){
                     if(p.getClass() == Service.class){
                         Service service = (Service)p;
                         return service.getPricePerHour();
                     }else{
                         Item item = (Item) p;
                         return item.getQuantity();
                     }
                 }

                 return null;
             }


         });
```

the values from string[] do not show but the rest of the data is fine.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're not adding the table to a null layout, right?

Comment: Can you explain your problem statement a bit more?

Comment: i add the table in here
this.add(table);
and my whole class extends JPanel...and also i have a gridlayout which is not null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have overridden `getColumnName()` that always returns same column name `"lol"` as per your code.

Simply return `names[c]` instead of `"lol";`

```
@Override
public String getColumnName(int c) {
    return names[c];
}

@Override
public int getColumnCount() {
    return names.length;
}
```

---

*Sample Code 1:* (using `DefaultTableModel`)

```
final String[] names = { "Type", "Company", "Shares", "Price" };
final Object[][] products = {
        { "Buy", "IBM", new Integer(1000), new Double(80.50) },
        { "Sell", "MicroSoft", new Integer(2000), new Double(6.25) },
        { "Sell", "Apple", new Integer(3000), new Double(7.35) },
        { "Buy", "Nortel", new Integer(4000), new Double(20.00) } };

JTable table = new JTable(new DefaultTableModel(products, names);

JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
// now add the scroll pane in `JPanel`
```

*Sample code 2:* (using `AbstractTableModel`)

```
final String[] names = { "Type", "Company", "Shares", "Price" };
final Object[][] products = {
        { "Buy", "IBM", new Integer(1000), new Double(80.50) },
        { "Sell", "MicroSoft", new Integer(2000), new Double(6.25) },
        { "Sell", "Apple", new Integer(3000), new Double(7.35) },
        { "Buy", "Nortel", new Integer(4000), new Double(20.00) } };

JTable table = new JTable(new AbstractTableModel() {

    @Override
    public String getColumnName(int col) {
        return names[col];
    }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return products.length;
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return names.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
        return products[row][col];
    }

});

JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
// now add the scroll pane in `JPanel`
```

snapshot:

[image]

Comment: Try with `DefaultTableModel` instead of `AbstractTableModel`.

Comment: Simply use `return products[row][col];`